# How to save photoshop pixel art

Tags: format, pixel, photoshop

I'm having some troubles right now with isometric pixel art. So I'm drawing this picture that is going to be uploaded later in the game, but when I save it and zoom it looks like this:

[image]

The picture became blurred and colors are not that bright. Is there anything I could do about it? How can I save it so it will be the same as in the photoshop (300% zoom)?

Would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: probably this question is most suitable to be posted here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please excuse me.
Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As Phlume said, you can use Vector base software like illustrator, CorelDraw, Inkscape (freeware) etc. and export it as a SVG image.

OR

for a quick fix, in a Photoshop you can create image in a 300% size (canvas size 3 times then require ) and export image in 96dpi. And further to reduce the image size for faster loading you can try https://tinypng.com/

And by the coding you can resize it to required size.

Comment: I have done this as well, but I bump to 600 dpi for better resolution for print. But again, something is to be said for using the right tool for the job - avector based program.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is a raster based program. To retain the clarity of the pixel artwork you should switch to a vector bed program such as illustrator. When you zoom in with illustrator the math recalculate to form clean lines from point to point. The blurry you see in photoshop is a product of the pixel data becoming compressed upon saving and finding a "happy medium" to represent the color within that region.

Comment: Thank you so much!